# django: Two different types of forms for same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django app where I have a model Settings as follows:

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    field2 = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    field3 = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    field4 = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    .....
```

Now I want to show these fields in one form as follows:

```
    Settings - field1 field2 field3 .....with check box select so that whichever field users choose they are displayed in another form to fill.
```

For example suppose user selects field1 and field 3 only out of all the fields then in my other form, I will ask users to fill the data for field1 and field3 only.

I am not getting the logic or direction how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You would ask users to fill data for field1 and field2 or to field1 and field3?

Comment: Ohh sorry! For field1 and field3 only. I have edited the question. Thanks for pointing out. I am looking to solve this using formsets.